# Composite video out from 74AHCxx gates with 16MHz clock. Insane?

Tags: digital-logic, ttl, video

just for fun and while waiting for other components to arrive I want to build a composite video out from available hardware. So please no suggestions to just by a propeller.

Available hardware:

- 16MHz quarz (and 4MHz if that helps)
- a bunch of 2/3/4 input and/or/xor/nand/nor/nxor gates (74AHCxx ICs)
- some latches, buffers, 4-bit counters, flip-flops, sram, mux (74AHCxx ICs)
- lots of resistors, lots of LEDs, some cpacitors, few diodes

So I was thinking of using the 4-bit counters and a comparator as clock input for a state machine. As first version the state would include the count for the next signal and output to the video out (0V, 0.3V, 07V). So basically a list of (duration, output) for a hardcoded checkerboard patterns or something. Second generation could then use the sram to fetch pixel data for a picture.

With a 16MHz clock I won't be able to hit the timing for composite video exactly. But should that be near enough for a monitor to understand? Or is the idea utterly insane?

---

Here is what I figured out so far. A PAL composite video is made up of the following parts (cycle counts for 16MHz in []):

- vertical blanking interval: 20x 64us

  1. pre equalizing pulse: 6x 32us

     - 2.2us -  2.4us @ 0.0V [ 35.2 -  38.4 =  37]
     - 29.8us - 29.6us @ 0.3V [476.8 - 473.6 = 475]
  2. equalizing pulse: 6x 32us

     - 27.4us - 27.2us @ 0.0V [438.4 - 435.2 = 437]
     - 4.6us -  4.8us @ 0.3V [ 73.6 -  76.8 =  75]
  3. post equalizing pulse: 6x 32us

     - 2.2us -  2.4us @ 0.0V [ 35.2 -  38.4 =  37]
     - 29.8us - 29.6us @ 0.3V [476.8 - 473.6 = 475]
  4. black lines: 11x 64us

     - see pixel lines below but with black (0.3V)
- odd field: 312 lines @ 64us each

  1. pre blank:     1.5us @ 0.3V     [24]
  2. hsync:         4.7us @ 0.0V     [75]
  3. post blank:    5.8us @ 0.3V     [93]
  4. Pixel data: adding black borders to get 768 pixel (256 * 3)

     - pre data:    2.0us @ 0.3V     [32]
     - pixel data: 48.0us @ 0.3-1.0V [768]
     - post data:   2.0us @ 0.3V     [32]
- half line: 1x 32us

  1. like pixel data but 320 cycles of black (32 + 256 + 32)
- vertical blanking interval: 20x 64us
- half line: 1x 32us
- even field: 312 lines @ 64us each

---

I'm thinking of basically doing 3 nested loops.

1. The innermost loop is just a delay sleeping for X cycles. Where X are the cycle counts above. I'm splitting 437, 475 and 768 into mulitples of 256 and remainder so I only need 8 bit delays: 24, 32, 37, 75, 93, 181, 219 and 256. Those can be done with 2 4bit counters.
2. The middle loop is more collection of linear state machines. Each has a start state and the next state is always state+1 until it hits an end state. Each state defines a delay (programming the innermost loop) and the output for the video out. The 2 4bit counters are providing the clock signal for these state machines. The collected state machines are: equalizing pulse, pre/post equalizing pulse, half line, vsync line, pixel line for a total of 32 states (including 4 invalid ones). The pixel line for example looks like this:

   ```
   state | count | end state | output | function
   ----- | ----- | --------- | ------ | --------
      24 |    24 |           | 0.3V   | pre blank
      25 |    75 |           | 0.0V   | hsync
      26 |    93 |           | 0.3V   | post blank
      27 |    32 |           | 0.3V   | pre pixel
      28 |   256 |           | 0.3-1V | pixel 0 - 255
      29 |   256 |           | 0.3-1V | pixel 256 - 511
      30 |   256 |           | 0.3-1V | pixel 512 - 767
      31 |    32 |     1     | 0.3V   | post pixel
   ```

   I can use a 4-bit counter here. 15 is an end state and 16 the begining of the next state machine so the 5th bit is static and I can get it from the outer loop.
3. The outermost loop has a list of state machines and how often to run each before transitioning to the next state and makes up one full field (two half frames) and then repeats:

   ```
   Meta | State | Loop | Function
   -----+-------+------+---------
      0 |     5 |    6 | pre equalizing pulse
      1 |     0 |    6 | equalizing pulse
      2 |     5 |    6 | post equalizing pulse
      3 |    16 |   11 | vsync line
      4 |    24 |  104 | pixel line (odd)
      5 |    24 |  104 | pixel line (odd)
      6 |    24 |  104 | pixel line (odd)
      7 |     8 |    1 | half line
      8 |     5 |    6 | pre equalizing pulse
      9 |     0 |    6 | equalizing pulse
     10 |     5 |    6 | post equalizing pulse
     11 |    16 |   11 | black line (v sync intervall)
     12 |     8 |    1 | half line
     13 |    24 |  104 | pixel line (even)
     14 |    24 |  104 | pixel line (even)
     15 |    24 |  104 | pixel line (even)
   ```

   Here I need 3 4-bit counters. One for the meta state and 2 combined as 8-bit loop counter.

Overall I get potentially 768 x 624 pixel with 32 pixel black border left and right. Lacking an eprom now I have to figure out the minterms for all the states, loop counts, count, endterm and video out so I can hardwire them with gates.

---

Generating output levels:

Using a 1k Ohm and 470 Ohm resistor combined with the 75 Ohm that composite is supposed to have gives nearly perfect levels for sync, black and white and even has a grey level:

```
    Signal | Sync | Output
     0 V   |  0 V |  0 V
     0 V   |  5 V |  0.30 V
     5 V   |  0 V |  0.64 V
     5 V   |  5 V |  0.95 V
```

The math works out nicely. But I'm uncertain wether I need to provide a 75 Ohm resistor or if the monitor supplies that. Google found two possible designs. Which one is correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0CLYv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PS: I will add more schematics as they develope.

Comment: Not entirely insane ... the ZX Spectrum produced colo(u)r composite video with little more than a 4MHz Z80.

Comment: I have used a CPLD chip to generate the Hsync and Vsync pulses for VGA and then you can generate video patterns to add from 0.3 to 1Vp into 75 Ohms. during the video time window.

Comment: That's entirely doable, with the caveat that your pixels won't be square. And a tip - it's relatively easy to get voltage levels if you use a tristate driver for the data intensity.

Comment: http://archive.siliconchip.com.au/cms/A_102724/article.html

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Could you give an example schematic for using tristates to generate the voltage levels?

Comment: @brhans - the composite video in the Spectrum was generated by the ULA, which ran at 14MHz.  It also had the benefit of using a dedicated video output modulator that performed the final signal mixing (an LM1889).